# Security Warning - Do you want to run this software?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, download, code-signing

A signed .exe is hosted in a server. A link is shown in the webpage to download and run the exe automatically.

While downloading, there is a pop-up shown (Security Warning - Do you want to run this software?). But in the pop-up the name of the signed .exe is not shown. Only publisher name is shown in the publisher field. Why so?

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you mind adding a screenshot of the warning?

Comment: Really sorry, can't share the screenshot.

Comment: This issue is resolved. The issue was with signing the .exe with the certificate. While signing the .exe using the "SignTool", we need to assign product name using "/d" option. Otherwise, while downloading the signed .exe only publisher name will be shown and not the product name.